# failed connecting with virtual machine

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, ether, nodes

I have 4 geth Nodes runnning on my PC
bootnode address is 192.168.1.2

the 5th node is running on Virtual machine with address ( 192.168.1.5 )

when i try to run the 5th node it doesn't sync with the network on 192.168.1.2